# Open Form with Button

Tags: c#

I want to open from an other Form with a button a Form. 
How can i do this?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form Grondstoffen = new Form();
Grondstoffen.Show();
}
}
```

I have tried to write this code but that opeens a Total different Form.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the **`Form`** with the **`Form you want to open`**, say if you want to open a Form named **myForm**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myForm Grondstoffen = new myForm();
    Grondstoffen.Show();
}
```